# Send notification to Android from sever without installing any app in it

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, android-wifi

Scenario: Suppose I have set up some WiFi and have one server in it. When android user connect to that WiFi area then I want to send notifications to those devices which is connected with WiFi. I don't want user, to install any app in their devices to receive notifications.

Can I use any system service to receive notification which is already running in the device? or something else which help me in this.

Comment: no you cannot, thankfully

Comment: You have to create an app and then using mqtt or fcm you can send push notification from server to app.

Comment: I don't want user, to install any app in their devices to receive notifications.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a login page to force users to allow notifications. After the user allows the notification, internet is free to use.

That way, you can send notifications without installing any app.